# Importing CSV with groovy ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: csv, groovy

I'm importing a CSV with Groovy which basically works, but not for all fields.

For some fields i get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

My input-file looks like this:

```
Bonbons /t  hustenbonbons-und-halsbonbons /t csd00301 /t true /t /t /t Bonbons /t   csd00298 /t "<h3>Bonbons</h3>\n<div align=""justify"">Bei Rachenproblemen wie z. B."    /t /t
```

The script looks like this:

```
  inFile.eachLine(){
    def fields = it.split("\t")
    def xsiteCode = fields[0]
    def seoName =   fields[1]
    def code =      fields[2] 
    def indi =      fields[3]
```

The error occurs when i try to read the field with the HTML etc. (`/t "<h3>Bonbons</h3>\n<div align=""justify"">Bei Rachenproblemen wie z. B."  /t`)

(I put in /t for the tabulator where he seperates the fields). Is it a problem with the HTML and special signs or why do i get this error and how can i evade it?

Comment: [Use a CSV parser](https://github.com/xlson/groovycsv)

Comment: How about you be more specific and describe when it works, and when it doesn't work?  Can you add a println statement right after the "split" call that prints out "it", and then a second println that prints out each of the field values?  The one that fails will likely only print out the "it".

Comment: As i stated lower i could with your help, clear the problem some more. The problem seems to be, that not every colum got data in all rows. I got some colums with all rows filled, those work, some colums don't have data in the last rows and they crash. But they got all the same number of seperators ("/t") so i don't get why this is a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException is caused whenever you call `fields[3]` and fields is smaller.  It's Groovy saying, "Hey, you wanted me to reach into the fourth bin, but there was no bin."

If you've verified that every line has at least 3 \t's that you're splitting on I would guess it's because you're parsing newline characters on their own (without 3 \t's)

The least invasive way to fix this in your code would be to use findAll to parse only valid lines (ones with 3 \t)

```
inFile.readLines().findAll{ it ==~ /(.*\\t.*){3}/ }.each{
    def fields = it.split("\t")
    def xsiteCode = fields[0]
```

Comment: Your hint is very good, that he claims fields is smaller... the "problem" is, that not all colums got data in this row. I got some colums with data in 12 rows and some colums with data in just 9 rows. BUT every colum contains 12 seperators "/t" so i don't get why there is this problem?

Comment: There's a very good chance that your file begins or ends with \n, which will be parsed as a new (empty/blank) line. Splitting that line would give you an array of size 1, you try grabbing the array's index at 4 but it doesn't have one, so your exception is thrown. Even if this isn't happening, it's a good idea to code defensively when it comes to external inputs like files.

Comment: Yeah, it worked when i put a row which was filled in all colums at the end of the table... So i guess this would work as well. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To reiterate what @tim_yates said, please save yourself the headache and consider using an existing CSV parser. It will allow you to move on to more important matters. Here's an example:

```
@Grab('com.opencsv:opencsv:3.5')

import com.opencsv.CSVReader

def reader = new StringReader('''Bonbons \t  hustenbonbons-und-halsbonbons \t csd00301 \t true \t \t \t Bonbons \t   csd00298 \t "<h3>Bonbons</h3>\n<div align=""justify"">Bei Rachenproblemen wie z. B."    \t \t''')

reader.withReader {
    new CSVReader(it, '\t' as char).each { line ->
        println line*.trim()
    }
}
```

The fields look like this:

```
[Bonbons, hustenbonbons-und-halsbonbons, csd00301, true, , , Bonbons, csd00298, <h3>Bonbons</h3>
<div align="justify">Bei Rachenproblemen wie z. B.", , ]
```

Answer (score 0):

One issue is to escape the regular expression as `"\\t"`. Another issue (for me) is to ensure that the text editor is not using soft-tabs.

```
def s = "a      b       c       d"
def fields = s.split("\\t")

assert 4 == fields.length
assert "a" == fields[0]
assert "b" == fields[1]
assert "c" == fields[2]
assert "d" == fields[3]
```

Comment: The escaping as "\\t" sadly does not help :/